# Line breaks in email report

Tags: macos, bash, shell

The following line in a shell script shows me the drive names currently mounted in OS X:

```
$ df -hlg | awk -F/ '/disk*/ {print $5}'
```

For example, this is the result:

```
User-BACKUP
User
Boot OS X
```

However, when that same shell script emails me a report, those line breaks disappear, and show up as:

```
User-BACKUP User Boot OS X
```

How can I impose the line breaks into the email report? That would make this much easier for users to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you don't quote the expansion on `` echo `df -hlg | awk -F/ '/disk*/ {print $5}'` ``

You could use

```
echo "`df -hlg | awk -F/ '/disk*/ {print $5}'`"
```

but `` echo "`cmd`" `` is just a roundabout way of writing `cmd`, so you can instead use

```
echo "Mounted external volumes:"
df -hlg | awk -F/ '/disk*/ {print $5}'
echo " "
```

PS: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out both of these issues.